# Can't add printer in ISE

Tags: powershell

So, I've been trying to add a printer in Power Shell, code is running but at the end there is no new printer...

```
$Printer = ([wmiclass]"win32_Printer").createinstance()

$Printer.Name = "MyWMIPrinter2"
$Printer.DriverName = "Brother DCP-J132W Printer"
$Printer.DeviceID = "MyWMIPrinter"
$Printer.Shared = $false
$Printer.PortName = "MyPrinterPort4"

$Printer.Put_
```

Comment: Does anything happen? Get any error messages etc.? What OS version are you using? From Windows 8 or later you can use `Add-Printer` https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/printmanagement/add-printer

Comment: `Put_` -> `Put()`

Comment: Ok, Put() - there is an error. Other than that - nothing happens, no error messages etc.

Comment: ...and what is the error?

Comment: It's working, thank you guys